# text keyboard appear even if I have set inputType to number edittext android

Tags: android, text, keyboard, numbers, android-edittext

I want to display the number keyboard.

Here is my code to do that. (This is an item of my list).

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checked_list_item_text"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checked_list_item_quatity"        
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/checked_list_item_quatity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Quantité"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on edittext, the keyboard displays the numbers but switches quickly to text and I have to click a second time to get  the number keyboard.

This issue occurs only the first time when I open the activity.

Comment: You might want to explain what the code, which you have posted here, does.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the input mode in your AndroidManifest.xml

I had the same issue when trying to get focus to an edittext field thats inside a listview. Adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the activity holding the listview solved the problem for me.

```
<activity android:name=".MyEditTextInListView"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work , but it could be something on the code side. Maybe you can force it programmatically:

```
EditText checkedInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.checked_list_item_quatity);
checkedInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```